# MySQL Combine People Names as in Mailing list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table Households that is a one to many relationship with a People table. I want to generate an address line for names like: 'HisFirst & HerFirst TheirLast', or something like 'Joe & Jane Doe'. This would serve as the first line of an address label. My query currently returns something like 'Joe Doe & Jane Doe'. So you see the last name is redundant. My query is below. How can I modify to get my desired result? I tried CASE statements based upon gender and IF/ELSE/THEN. I also tried to nest both types. I finally tried concatenating 2 select statements, but kept getting multiple rows returned - so MySQL raised an exception.

```
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(People.FName, ' ', People.LName ORDER BY Gender DESC SEPARATOR ' & ') AS `HouseholdName`
FROM Households 
LEFT JOIN People
  ON Households.HouseholdID = People.HouseholdID 
GROUP BY
  Households.HouseholdID
```

Gender is 2 for males and 1 for females.

If only 1 person belongs to a "Household" it returns that one person's name as 'Jane Doe', so that part works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to do a join since `People` already has the `HouseholdID`.

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(People.FName ORDER BY Gender DESC SEPARATOR ' & '), ' ', People.LName)
  AS `HouseholdName`
FROM People
GROUP BY
  People.HouseholdID, People.LName;
```

Comment: Works great! I totally overlooked the CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT construct. Got another related question if it's allowed here: what if the two people listed do not have the same last name?

Comment: My answer takes care of that too as the grouping is done by the `familyID` and the `LName`. If they have no name the grouping will be done by their familyID.

Comment: Well, actually no. If I use the GROUP BY as in the sample and the two people have different last names, they are separated out in the query results as two separate lines, each with his/her own 'FName LName'. If I remove People.LName from the GROUP BY, which would seem to be the cause, for couples with differing last names it returns 'HisFirst & HerFirst HerLast' whereas I want 'HisFirst HisLast & HerFirst HerLast'.